# How can I rewrite a URL, splitting the path into separate querystring arguments?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I want to rewrite an URL such as: mysite.com/Section/Subsection/SubSubSection into 
mysite.com/index.php?s=Section&sub1=SubSection&sub2=SubSubSection

I wrote this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?s=$1&sub1=$2&sub2=$3
```

But the problem is that Section, SubSection and SubSubSection are not mandatory at all, but if I insert some '?' character it goes on Internal Server Error...

(I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/([^/]*))?(/([^/]*))?/?$ /index.php?s=$1&sub1=$3&sub2=$5
```

but it doesn't work)

Another problem is that there are other URLs that should not be edited, such as /res/img/logo.png.

The site in question is dynamic, so I don't know the section names beforehand. I know URLs that should be excluded, of course.

Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it not possible to just process the request_uri in php instead? Seems it would be easier and I think CMS's like Wordpress, Drupal, and Joomla. And I think Zend process the urls in php once everything gets redirected index.php

Comment: But if I redirect to index.php, the request_uri is always 'index.php' when I try to process it within php, or not?

Comment: That's the thing, the request_uri won't change to index.php, so long as you don't do a redirect in your rewrite rule. Take a look at a Wordpress .htaccess file for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like that ...

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z]*)/?$ /index.php?s=$1&sub1=$2&sub2=$3
```

regards,

Mimiz